# Trying to understand how to design the gate of a frequency counter

Tags: rf, frequency, frequency-measurement

I´m trying to design a frequency counter for my physics class. My teacher demanded that we build it using a 32768 Hz crystal and 4060 ic. In my research i stumbled across this design:

[image]

I don´t have a good knowledge on digital electronics and i have no idea on how i can fisically build the main gate and gate/flip-flop blocks (which ics to use and stuff). I deeply appreciate any help.

Comment: Go to the datasheet for the 4060 ( https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC4060A-D.PDF .) They show you how to make a Pierce oscillator using your xtal. Follow the design procedure and you are done with that part. Then go here: http://www.qsl.net/pa2ohh/sfreq.htm and read. Then tell us what you don't like about that web page, or what doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I hear the term "frequency counter", I think of a device which measures and displays the frequency one signal with respect to another. The drawing you posted is a start at building one of these. They are also sometimes called "time interval counters".

Since your professor only instructed you to use a crystal and a [CD4060](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CD4060BC-D.pdf), I'm guessing that your task is to just build a simple clock using the 14-stage binary counter. But either way, you start the process the same:

**First:** Wire your crystal to *Pins 10 and 11* like this:
[image: crystal wiring]

**Second:** Now you can choose the desired signal from the counter's stage pins.

A commonly wanted signal is 1 Hz. Did you notice that your **32.768 kHz** oscillator is a **power of 2**? If you divide this number (32,768) by two, 15 times, you will get 1 Hz.

But since the CD4060 is a 14-stage counter (and we need 15 stages to get 1 Hz), you can only get a **2 Hz** signal, on *Pin 3* (Q<sub>14</sub>).

You can, however, add an additional stage manually. For example, this circuit will give you 1 Hz (and beyond):

[image: 1 Hz schematic]
[circuit reference](http://hackersbench.com/Projects/1Hz/)

**Finally**
To complete the design of an actual frequency counter, you can basically now just repeat the process. Clock a second counter with the signal that you intend to measure, and gate the chip's operation with the 1 Hz signal created above. The gate should serve as both a reset to the second counter, and a latch to send the previous measurement to the display (or receiving circuitry).

The second counter will therefore tell you how many oscillations occurred within your 1 Hz (1-second) time period - and oscillations per second = frequency in Hz.